# Can if statements be combined with a variable assignment using pattern matching?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

Example of the code that I am talking about:

```
if (sender is Panel p)
{
    if (p.Enabled == false)
    {
        AMButton.Checked = false;
        PMButton.Checked = false;
        currentSelectedTime = null;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to "do something more" with the variable p once its been cast in the first if statement thus combining the two statements?

Comment: Please explain more?

Comment: Something such as if(sender is Panel p.Enabled). Combining the two if statements into one line like that. Does that make sense? I've tried different combinations of syntax I just can't get it right by guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Something such as if(sender is Panel p.Enabled). Combining the two if
>   statements into one line like that. Does that make sense?

```
if(sender is Panel p && p.Enabled)
```

or to get real ugly

```
if(sender is Panel p && (p.Enabled = somethingElse) == ((someInt = anotherInt) == 5))
```

Comment: I guess the second line should test equality, not assign a value.

Comment: @nngmg well the assignment was on purpose , however i can make it uglier with a test

Comment: @AlexKennedy doo eeet. Actually my recommendation is just use plain vanilla code, the more fancy you get the more you look back in think whyyy when you have a bug

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer of

```
if (sender is Panel p && p.Enabled)
```

is correct and works right now.

In C# 8, pattern matching will (probably) be extended to allow property matching:

```
if (sender is Panel { Enabled: true } p)
```

This looks a little alien right now, but it's likely to be more and more idiomatic, particularly when matching multiple properties. The recursive patterns can be used to introduce more pattern variables too, and you don't need a pattern variable for the "outer" pattern. For example, suppose we only needed the `Tag` property from the panel, we could use:

```
if (sender is Panel { Enabled: true, Tag: var tag })
{
    // Use tag in here
}
```

Comment: Awesome insight! Good to know what is going to happen in the future